# whats the extent of character building allowed here?

Tags: discussion

i made an account here to ask questions on the viability of mine and my friends work-in-progress webcomic, specifically the biology and astronomical bodies.
between me and my friend i am making this part of the comic while she makes the characters and setting and such, with overall plot and things being shared.

**what im wondering, is if she can join this site or use my account to ask about character design and/or character creation and most other things like that. if i cant, can you point me to any sites or other sections of StackExchange where i can?**

Comment: Depending on what sort of character creation concepts she is looking for she *might* get something of value from RPG.SE...maybe?

Answer (score 7):

Two points to consider

- On **Worldbuilding**, you are not supposed to ask a question about character development and/or plots. Apart from the [help](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), there are some discussions about it around here. Last in date [Questions about single individual actions](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2654/questions-about-single-individual-actions). As you can read in there, it is possible under some circumstances to ask questions related to some character. But I suppose that's not what you had in mind.
- On other SE sites. You might consider [Writers SE](https://writers.stackexchange.com/). But there again, you should consider if it is [on-topic](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or not. But Writers is intended more for writing techniques, general suggestions about how to build a plot or even a character, but strictly speaking a character development will be off-topic.  As far as I'm aware, there aren't any specific sites dedicated to characters and/or plot development. *Why?* Because it is too specific. The main idea of SE questions is to offer a solution that might be interesting not only to the original poster, but also to someone else later. Character development questions tend to be either too narrow (not useable by someone else), too opinion-based (*What's the best hair color*) or even what we call here, [Idea Generation](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/522/whats-wrong-with-idea-generation-questions).

Nevertheless, you might also peruse around WB and Writers, as there are a number of characters-related questions. That would give you a feeling of what is allowed and what isn't.

Comment: thank you for this useful information, ill tell my friend

Comment: Do note that we share one diamond mod with [writers.se]. (That's Monica Cellio.)

Comment: On Writers, questions about *what to write* are off-topic (we're about the *how*, not the *what*).  So to the extent that character development falls into that category, it would be off-topic -- but we do have *process* questions, like how to portray a character with a very different perspective and such.  So it's worth looking around there.  All that said, the Writers chat room tends to be active (especially on Tuesdays, our writing-challenge day), so you can pop in there to discuss ideas.  RPG would be another place to look; if their chat is active I'd try there.